# CLLocationManager delegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code in my ViewController:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}


-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    int desiredHA = 200;
    RemoteDataController *rdc = [[RemoteDataController alloc]init];
    double ha = newLocation.horizontalAccuracy;

    if (ha <= desiredHA)
    {
        [rdc addLoc];
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
        return;
    }
}


-(void)startLogging
{
    if(self.locationManager==nil)
    {
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    }

    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        NSLog(@"Start Location Tracking");
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
}

-(void)addLocResponse
{
    NSLog(@"send checkin response");
    self.silenceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self
                         selector:@selector(onTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)onTick:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [self startLogging];
}
```

Then my RemoteDataController.m file looks like this:

```
@implementation RemoteDataController

-(void)addLoc
{
    ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [vc addLocResponse];
    NSLog(@"Add Loc");
}

@end
```

I know this looks stupid right now but I stripped out a lot of the details of it so it's not too complicated.

My question is when I call `addLocResponse` from the RemoteDataController class the timer runs and then hits the `onTick` which fires of `startLogging` again. I can see it's running `startLogging` again from the NSLog but it does not run the locationManager delegate again.

If I keep all this in the `ViewController` it works fine but when I try to go out to `RemoteDataController` and back it does not work.

I am just trying to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

This is iOS6.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you implement `-locationManager:didFailWithError:` and is it being called?   Might be a clue in there, but this looks like it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried that. It's not firing off either.

Comment: Grasping at straws: have you tried an `NSLog(@"%@", self.locationManager)` just after `NSLog(@"Start Location Tracking");`

Comment: One other possibility.  If the `-stopUpdatingLocation` is somehow not getting called (or going to `nil`), then `CLLocationManager` won't send another update to your delegate regardless of how many times you send `startUpdatingLocation`, so that may be another potential vector for failure.

Comment: How is the `locationManager` property defined? If you are using ARC and the property is `weak` then you may have issues. Use `strong` instead.

Comment: locatioManager is defined as strong. I was concerned about that also.

Comment: The code looks like you end up with an infinite loop, creating different instances of RDC and in turn new instances of VC which create more RDC's and so on.  Also I see you're trying to turn on/off locationManager, why don't you create it with once instance of it and turn it on/off using startUpdatingLocation/stopUpdatingLocation? You don't need to alloc init it every time you need to turn it on.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using a correct initializer for your view controller. Also, put a breakpoint on the dealloc method of your ViewController instance. Chances are it's being deallocated (if you are using ARC) because you are not doing anything with it (modal presentation or push).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Can you please explain what you mean by "You are not using a correct initializer for your view controller".

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Most of the time, you should be using initWithNibName:bundle:. If you have an UITableViewController subclass, you should be using initWithStyle: . Check the documentation of the parent view controller  class of your view controller.